# How to solve unalignable index issue during copy between multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have two dataframes `df` and `hash_file` like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'source_description':['test1', 'test1','test2','test3','test5']})

hash_file = pd.DataFrame({'source_code':['test1','test2','test3','test5'],
                          'hash_id':[911,512,713,814]})

id_file =  hash_file.set_index(['source_code'])['hash_id']


cols = ["seq_id","desc","key_id"]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

I would like to do 2 things

a) copy the `source_description` to `test_df['desc']` column

b) copy the corresponding `hash_id` to `test_df['key_id']` column

While I already tried the below, for some weird reason it returns `NA` for all my `key_id` rows

```
test_df["seq_id"] = df.index + 1
test_df["desc"] = df['source_description']
test_df["key_id"] = df['source_description'].map(id_file)
```

However, when I try separately only the below line, it works fine and am able to see the key_ids displayed in jupyter notebook prompt.

```
 df['source_description'].map(id_file)
```

but when I assign it to `test_df['key_id]` for some reason, I see only `NA`

Am I making any mistake while creating the `test_df` and assigning column names?

I also tried clearing `jupyter notbook cache, reset the kernel` did everything but the still the code returns `NA`. While what I have shown above is only 3 columns, my real data has more than 25 columns and I do similar assignment options for all 25 columns. Is it like Jupyter notebook became tired of assignment? I don't know why the correct code is returning incorrect result

Can help me with this please?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
seq_id    desc    key_id
  1       test1    911
  2       test1    911
  3       test2    512
  4       test3    713
  5       test5    814
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.merge`:

```
In [2527]: test_df = df.merge(hash_file, left_on='source_description', right_on='source_code')[['source_description', 'hash_id']]

In [2529]: test_df.columns = ['desc', 'key_id']

In [2534]: test_df = test_df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'seq_id'})

In [2535]: test_df.seq_id = test_df.seq_id + 1

In [2536]: test_df
Out[2536]: 
   seq_id   desc  key_id
0       1  test1     911
1       2  test1     911
2       3  test2     512
3       4  test3     713
4       5  test5     814
```

**OR:**

You can tweak your code like this:

```
test_df["seq_id"] = df.index + 1
test_df["desc"] = df['source_description']
test_df["key_id"] = test_df['desc'].map(id_file)
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted, Any idea on whats wrong with my code?

Comment: You don't actually need to create a test_df separately, instead just subset the columns of `df.merge` output. This should be more efficient.

Comment: @TheGreat Have added explanation what's wrong with your code in my answer. Please check.

Comment: The problem is even if I copy the `df[source_description]`, I only see `NA`.. Something weird.. Therefore, `key_id` is also `NA`.

Comment: But if I just type `df['source_description'].map(id_file)` in my jupyter cell without assigning it to `test_df['key_id`], I do see the `key_ids`... The problem is when I assign it, it returns NA. Am not sure whether any issue with my jupyter notebook or something else

Comment: omg, I just found out that the issue was due to unalignable index...

Comment: @TheGreat Great. But `df.merge` works with unalignable indexes as well.

Answer (score 2):

This issue of `NA` is due to unalignable index.

Reset the index of both the dataframes `test_df` and `df`. Then try the code in the question, it should work fine

I did the below

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)  #updated drop command as per suggestion below
test_df = test_df.reset_index(drop=True) #updated drop command as per suggestion below
test_df["seq_id"] = df.index + 1
test_df["desc"] = df['source_description']
test_df["key_id"] = df['source_description'].map(id_file)
```